# Cannot generate angular module with routing in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a problem to generate modules with routing in ionic project.

I created new ionic project from `ionic start routing blank`. And I generate module with routing as the following commands.

```
ionic g m heroes --route heroes --module app-routing.module
```

or

```
ng g m heroes --route heroes --module app-routing.module
```

I got this error.

```
File heroes/heroes.module.ts does not exist.
[ERROR] Could not generate module.
```

If I generate modules like this in pure Angular project, it perfectly work.
I used Ionic 5.4.4 and Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

Use path relative to your base-href that is `src/app`. try like below.

```
ng g m heroes --route --module app-routing.module
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated the answer, Please try that and let me know. Issue is with Ionic, it is trying search the heroes module , since it is not found , it is throwing an error.

Comment: It is generate module file only. The other files such as components, html. etc. are missing to generate.

Comment: for that u need to use another command which generates component, like ng g c ****, probably both cannot be achieved in single command even in pure angular project.